# selectCheckboxMenu: items are shown with bold font

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I don't know how to remove the bold property to the font of selectCheckboxMenu items

declared in the .xhtml:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-selectonemenu-trigger{width:24px !important;margin-left:9px !important;}
    .ui-selectcheckboxmenu-trigger{width:24px !important;margin-left:9px !important;}
    .ui-selectcheckboxmenu-header:before{font-weight:normal;margin-left:10px;content: "Selecciona/Deselecciona todos";}
    .ui-selectcheckboxmenu-label{font-weight:normal !important;}
    .ui-selectcheckboxmenu-header{font-weight:normal !important;}
</style>
```

selectCheckboxMenu declared in the .xhtml:

```
<p:selectCheckboxMenu  id="adaptacionDiscapacidadSelectOne" 
                       value="#{solicitudMB.listaAdaptacionLabelSelected}"
                       panelStyle="width:500px" filter="false"
                       label="Selec. adaptación/es" style="font-weight:normal !important;"
                       styleClass="field-column-2">
    <f:ajax event="change" update=":generalform:accordionPanel:form_datosConvocatoria3:customPanel5 @form"
            render=":generalform:accordionPanel:form_datosConvocatoria3:customPanel5"
            listener="#{solicitudMB.isOtraAdaptSelected()}"/>
    <f:ajax event="toggleSelect" update=":generalform:accordionPanel:form_datosConvocatoria3:customPanel5 @form"
            render=":generalform:accordionPanel:form_datosConvocatoria3:customPanel5"
            listener="#{solicitudMB.isOtraAdaptSelected()}"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{solicitudMB.listaAdaptacionLabel}"/>
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

Thank you in advance!

[SOLUTION] by @Geinmachi
add this in the CSS
.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-panel[id*="adaptacionDiscapacidadSelectOne"] .ui-selectcheckboxmenu-item label {
    font-weight:normal !important;
}

Comment: It is `render` not `update` in `<f:ajax>`. You had better replace `<f:ajax>` with `<p:ajax>`.

Comment: Are you aware of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8768317?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every label in `p:selectOneMenu` whose id contains phrase `adaptacionDiscapacidadSelectOne` will not be bold:

```
.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-panel[id*="adaptacionDiscapacidadSelectOne"] .ui-selectcheckboxmenu-item label {
    font-weight:normal !important;
}
```